# Version 5.7 of autoindent Python in Notepad++ half works

Tags: python, notepad++

Autoindenting doesn't work on Notepad++ correctly. I can't find the equivalent [SciTE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SciTE) file.
menu *Settings* -> *Preferences* -> *MISC* -> *Auto-indent* is checked. I can't find any other Python indent settings other than menu *Settings* -> *Preferences* -> lang/tab settings -> default tab settings -> Python -> size 4, replace by space.

```
if True:
pass
```

But it does continue indenting if manually indented:

```
if True:
    #foo
    pass
```

In SciTE it works as intended. I found the variable that's controlling this:

```
# python.properties
statement.indent.$(file.patterns.py)=5 class def elif else except finally for if try while with
```

scite:

```
if True:
    pass
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question deserves an updated answer: there is now the plugin [Python Indent](http://npp-wiki.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Plugin_Central#P) that, when enabled (Main Menu > Extension > Python Indent > Enable) auto-indents during typing Python. New lines after a colon `:` like in `def foo():` indents the following line, resulting in:

```
def foo():
    """ works """
    pass
```

With current versions of Notepad++ comes the Plugin Manager (Main Menu > Extensions > Plugin Manager), that makes installing the plugin very easy.

Answer (score 2):

Most developers of text editing programs misuse the name auto-indent, as does Notepad++, which only has "maintain indentation".

You could use the plugin [NppAutoIndent](http://sourceforge.net/projects/npp-plugins/files/NppAutoIndent/).

The description at the *[Directory for Notepad++ plugins](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/notepad-plus/index.php?title=Plugin_Central)* says:

> NppAutoIndent plugin has 'smart'
>   indentation for C-style languages,
>   such as C/C++, PHP, Java and such.
>
> It's the first release so don't expect
>   it to be flawless, and of course it
>   might not be completely to your
>   preferences ;)
>
> There is NO support for HTML/XML and
>   such, maybe later, tag matching is
>   much more difficult to implement.

Another indenter is [UniversalIndentGUI](http://universalindent.sourceforge.net/), which expressly claims support for Python in [its features list](http://universalindent.sourceforge.net/features.php), and is available as a Notepad++ plugin.

Comment: @Ciantic: If it was you that accepted my answer, just a remark that accepting the answer and assigning the bounty are two different actions. For the later, use the Bounty button.

Comment: No it was not me. NppAutoIndent does not work for Python. I'll wait if someone comes up solution that helps with Python, if none appears I accept this too.

Comment: @Ciantic: I have added UniversalIndentGUI, which could maybe do better for Python.